# Tortoise Hg red line after merging

Tags: version-control, mercurial, version, tortoisehg

Hi after merging i have this red line what does it mean?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graph view on the left shows your different branches of development, e.g. different sets of changes (probably done by different people):

Person A made changes at revision 17, 20 and 25.
Person B (or the rest of the team) made the other changes...and at some point the changes have to be merged together again.

The different line colors are just for clarity, and the colors are assigned randomly, I think.
*(see the TortoiseHG docs [for a screenshot with more lines](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.7/workbench.html#module-workbench.dialog))*

In your example, the blue and red line connecting at revision 26 means that you (or someone else) merged revisions 24 and 25 (the blue dots where the lines come from).

The same happened at revision 24, where revision 20 and 23 were merged.

---

The fact that you are asking this shows me that the concept of branching and merging in Mercurial (or any VCS) seems to be new to you.
Maybe you should read a bit about branching and merging. Here are some good tutorials:

- [Tutorial - Merging Changes](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TutorialMerge)
- [Merging](http://hginit.com/04.html)
- [A tour of Mercurial: merging work](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html)

Comment: i understand complatly the concept of branching and merging, but i thouoght that sth is wrong here cause of red color :)

Comment: can you confirmt that red color doesn't indicate any problem?

Comment: @kosnkov: Yes, absolutely. Red just seems to be the first color besides blue that TortoiseHG uses for its graph. If you still don't believe me, clone the official repositories for [Mercurial](http://selenic.com/hg) or [TortoiseHG](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg) to your machine, open them in TortoiseHG and look at the number of red lines :-)